How to permanently enable passwordless ssh to root user?
I am trying to enable passwordless ssh between two servers. I followed the instructions mentioned here - How to set up passwordless SSH access for root user
But everytime I try to login to the server, it asks me for the password. Once I enter the password, it works fine for a few hours, then it is reset to its usual state where it starts asking me for the password again. How can I persist the changes?

It might help if you show us your actual ssh command and the output. Perhaps also with -v (verbose) option. (Please edit that into the question rather than adding it as a comment, so that it's clear to future readers.)

Try running the ssh command with the verbose setting (ssh -vvvv username@hostname) and reading the log output. You also should check the permissions on your ~/.ssh directory on the server
